# Equations on multiple lines

Tags: formatting

Is there a more efficient way to write a series of equations?

```
\begin{equation*}
    B'(x)=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{-(1-x)^2 +x^2}{x^2(1-x)^2}=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -x^2+2x-1+x^2=0 \qquad \text{Con $x\neq 0 \wedge x\neq 1$}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    2x-1=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    x=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Have a look at `align*` from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is @JouleV's comment as an answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
B'(x)&=0\\
-\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}&=0\\
\frac{-(1-x)^2 +x^2}{x^2(1-x)^2}&=0\\
-x^2+2x-1+x^2&=0 \qquad \text{Con } x\neq 0 \wedge x\neq 1 \\
2x-1&=0\\
x&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]